# Passing data type in a construct

Tags: php

I'am trying to pass a data of type string to a construct to ensure that a string is always passed

In my reset password class I have

```
class RequestResetPassword extends Mailable
  {

  public function __construct(User $user, String $resettoken)
   {

   }
```

The user part is okay as it is of type user Model but how do i go about the access token part by stating that it must always be a string

The above generates an error

```
App string not found.
```

Comment: It should be "string", with a lower case "s".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be `string` (lowercase), since is not a class. Something like:

```
public function __construct(User $user, string $resettoken)
{

}
```

Check the [PHP documentation on type declarations](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration).